# check format image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to check `.svg` format image or not. You need something similar:

```
Widget widget;
imageName == svg ? widget = SvgPicture.network(imageName)
                 : widget = Image(image: imageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the **imageName** is a url with extension **.svg** or **.jpg/.png** etc.

You can check and display the widget in this way:

```
(imageName.contains('svg')) ? SvgPicture.network(imageName) : Image.network(imageName)
```

or if imageName isn't a url, you can replace widget: Image.asset(imageName)

Answer (score 0):

var widget = Image(
image: imageName,
errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => SvgPicture.network(imageName),
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).